# Kendo combobox.value(x) not working correctly

Tags: javascript, combobox, kendo-ui

I'm trying to set value of kendo combobox dynamically, but when trying like:

```
var lvl1 = $("#level1Id").data("kendoComboBox");                        
var lvl2 = $("#level2Id").data("kendoComboBox");

var l2value = lvl2.value(); // save value for later use
... // do something that includes changing lvl2.value 
lvl2.value(l2value.toString()); // set lvl2.value back to previous
```

the combobox value sets to "Code" field - for example - 2, instead of "Value/Text" field - "corresponding value of l2value code". I understand, that value(x) takes string parameter, so I've tried different conversion methods (int->string), but no luck. Am I missing something here? Setting this combobox value dynamically is essential for me, so any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I'm changing the combobox filter just before setting value the second time. Could that be the reason here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pvanhouten/qb8rD/1/.  I tried to show how you can get both the currently selected text (apple) and the selected value (1).  You can also type a value into the text input to set the selected value of the combo box.  If you type in `apple`, it will select the `apple` entry from the combo box.  If you type in something that isn't in the combo box list, it will set the value of the combo box to that value and both the id and text for the currently selected item will be the value that you type in.  Does that help at all?

Comment: Thanks, I discovered few days ago that I was trying to set combobox to value that was not in options list. Silly mistake, but was hard to notice though. So your guess was right.